# Where to start with writing a small h.264 encoder

Tags: h.264

I need to write a very small, very simple h.264 encoder. I started with hello264 (the world's smallest h.264 encoder) and I'm starting to understand a few of the basics.  I'm also trying to wade through the h.264 spec, but I'm finding it difficult to understand without examples.  I've also got source code for x264 and ffmpeg, but that's a lot of code to wade through and I don't understand the principals of where to start. For example, I'm only looking to start with simple intra frame compression. Any advice on a good book, blog, article, document, etc. is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote this one, you may find it helpful to start from.

http://www.cardinalpeak.com/blog/?p=488

Apologies - I edited this now that I see you started with my encoder. I don't see a delete option....

Comment: Ben, the example is great... I was curious if you ever made a super tiny h264 encoder using java?  I was trying to convert yours but seemed to fail miserably as the "sizeof" function doesn't exist in java

Comment: in java you should know the size of your data types.

Answer (score 2):

The best answer seems to be the book "The H.264 Advance Video Compression Standard", by Iain E. Richardson.

Comment: I have this book and I can tell you that although it helps you understand the techniques, it says nothing about the schema of an mpeg file and how to decode or encode into one. If it would include something simple like some pseudocode on how to pick apart frames and start decoding them it would have been much better.